# One website not connecting over shared connection

Tags: ubuntu, home-networking, routing, iptables

A website is not opening on a computer that's connected via shared connection (not exactly "shared"). Pinging the website gets `Packet filtered` message.

The setup of my home network is done by [Ubuntu manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing):

**Master PC**: Ubuntu 9.10. eth1 for provider's connection, eth2 for the internal, with dhcp3 that gives IP to the slave pc. My ISP provides internet via VPN: LAN is accessible via DHCP, to get Internet I use `pppd` and a script with manual routing with *iptables* (I don't check the "share this connection" box, it won't work at all this way).

Here's the script:

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -j MASQUERADE
```

And the iptables rules on the *master PC*:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.0.0/24       anywhere            ctstate NEW 
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

On this one, I write the website address, and it works perfectly.

**Slave PC**: Ubuntu 9.04 laptop. Ethernet connection with DHCP. Can't open or ping the website, `packet filtered`. The Iptables rules on slave PC are:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Right now I've seen only www.s7.ru (89.249.20.27) filtered by this issue, and I can't say whether other sites are affected: so far we haven't noticed an issue with any of them.

I've tried some tests and here's what I see:

1. nslookup works on both PCs
2. ping doesn't work on any ("packet filtered" message)
3. `telnet www.s7.ru 80` then `GET /` returns a "301 Moved permanently" message from the server on **both** computers.
4. Still, Opera/Firefox can open this website **only from Master PC**. The slave PC infinitely waits for reply from server.

**How can I find the sourse of the problem?** (<s>I guess it's Iptables rule</s>)

Comment: Without seeing your iptables script, there's no way to know which rule is causing your problems.

Comment: Added the script

Comment: one particular website or all of them?

Comment: @Phoshi: I guess that follows.  This message will self-destruct...

Answer (score 1):

Since the default policy for all the chains on the gateway machine  is accept I think that this problem has nothing to do with iptables rules. Its more likely due to ppp/vpn MTU packet sizes.